# Azure Media Player breaking upon video play

Tags: azure, azure-media-services

I've got a really strange issue. Azure's media player was working just fine until a few days ago, when I actually needed it working, and since then it hasn't. I've attached a picture so you can see what I am looking at whenever I press play:

[image]

This is the code for the player:

```
<video id="azuremediaplayer" class="azuremediaplayer amp-default-skin amp-big-play-centered" tabindex="0" autoplay controls width="100%" margin="0" margin="0px" poster="{{object.thumbnail.url}}" data-setup='{"logo": { "enabled": false },"nativeControlsForTouch": false, "plugins": {"ga":{ "eventsToTrack": ["playerConfig", "loaded", "playTime", "percentsPlayed", "start", "end", "play", "pause", "error", "buffering", "fullscreen", "seek", "bitrate"], "debug": false}}}'>
    <source
    src="{{object.ingest_url}}"
    type="application/vnd.ms-sstr+xml"
    />
    <p class="amp-no-js">
        To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a web browser that supports HTML5 video
    </p>
</video>
```

I am using version 2.2.4:

```
<link href="http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.2.4/skins/amp-default/azuremediaplayer.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src= "http://amp.azure.net/libs/amp/2.2.4/azuremediaplayer.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

My own fault, the Streaming Endpoint was shut down accidentally.